# Advanced permissions with couchdb

Tags: permissions, authorization, couchdb, couchapp

We have a couchapp application with multiple users and a complex system of permissions.
Our models are of two kinds: Foo and bar.

Users have admin access to their own Foo and Bar, and can be given permission to see, change and delete other people's Foo and bar.

Example:

User Sabrina has these models:

```
Foo {
  _id: 1
}
Foo {
  _id: 2
}
Bar {
  _id:1
}
Bar {
  _id:2
}
```

Of course the real models are larger documents.

She wants to give Giulia read access to her Foos, and read and write access to her first bar. She also wants Giulia not to be able to see her second Bar.

How can we model this kind of permissions in couchdb?

This is the solution we are using, but it seems a lot complex and we wonder if there's a simpler one:

We have a selection of roles:
`{username}:admin`: can read, write, delete everything on every database related to the user
`{username}:foos:read`: can read every document in the foos database related to the user
`{username}:foos:write`: can write every document in the foos database related to the user
`{username}:{bar}:read`: can read the Bar database related to the user
`{username}:{bar}:write`: can write the Bar database related to the user

When Sabrina register to the app, we create a new `sabrina-foos` database, and we give to the user Sabrina the role `sabrina:admin`.

The `sabrina-foos` database is created with a `_security` document granting access to roles `sabrina:admin`, `sabrina:foos:read`, `sabrina:foos:write`.

The `sabrina-foos` database is created with a validation function which allows write access to the roles `sabrina:admin`, `sabrina:foos:write`.

When Sabrina decides to let Giulia see her foos, we give Giulia the role `sabrina:foos:read`

When Sabrina creates a new Bar called 'Bar 1', we create a new `sabrina-bar_1` database.

The `sabrina-bar_1` database is created with a _security document granting access to roles `sabrina:admin`, `sabrina:bar_1:read`, `sabrina:bar_1:write`

The `sabrina-bar_1` database is created with a validation function which allows write access to the roles `sabrina:admin`, `sabrina:bar_1:write`.

Of course, being this a CouchApp, the creation of databases and editing of user models is handled by a Node Process.

Comment: Have you considered externalizing the authorization altogether? Look at XACML for instance.

Comment: @DavidBrossard XACML looks nice. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your design is good. From your question it looks like you want document level authentication. 
couchdb offers no protection on individual documents so the 
only choice left is to partition the documents by databases and set read and write permissions on them.

There are two alternatives. The easiest one is to use 
[rcouch's validate docs on read](https://github.com/rcouch/rcouch/wiki/Validate-documents-on-read). I am not too 
sure but I think in couch db 2.0 all of rouch's features have been merged so if you are willing to wait a bit you can use couchdb 2.0 (it should be out any time now!) instead.

Another method is to do what you are doing but in a [_users](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/security.html?highlight=security) database. In a `_users` database you can 
create users and authenticate them with `_sessions` api. So here is how it will work.

1. Every new user that you create will go in a `_users` database.
2. Within the user document you can store a list of what documents the user is allowed to view or if you are 
   worried that a single user document will grow too big then just store a pointer to maybe a database that contains the 
   actual list the user can view.
3. Use the `_sessions` api first to authenticate the user and then to get a list of docs that the user is authorized 
   to read or edit.
4. Finally fetch those documents and `show` it to the user.

The advantage of this method is that you will need a minimum of 2 and at most 3 http queries. One to authenticate and get a pointer to the list. Second to get the actual list of documents to be fetched. Third to fetch those documents.  In return your architecture is greatly simplified.

A very cool property of `_users` database is that you can increase the auth cache size in the config to hold the `_user` objects in the memory so the access times will be very fast.

> What If I have ten thousand documents but I can only retrieve one of them? Would the function be called ten thousand times?

I don't have rcouch installed at the moment but there is an easy way to test this by logging:-

```
function(doc, userCtx) {
    log("function called");
    if ((typeof doc.name !== 'undefined') && (doc.name != userCtx.name)) {
        throw({unauthorized: userCtx.name + ' cannnot read ' + doc._id});
    }
}
```

The log function will print a log message in the log files and also on the console couchdb is running on so you can see for yourself how many times the update function is being called. Would be nice if you could share the results :)

Comment: Rcouch could be the way to go. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if results are cached somehow. What If I have ten thousand documents but I can only retrieve one of them? Would the function be called ten thousand times?

Comment: Over the weekend I'll try it